# Laravel Helpers in Pug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm developing a Laravel CMS but I'm using pug as template instead of blade, my question is how can I do to use, for example `{{ asset() }}` or `{{ route() }}` in my pugs template?

Comment: You might have a lot of trouble with this, as `pug` looks to be a `js` templating engine, but `blade` is a `php` one. Also, `asset()` and `route()` are not exclusive to `blade`; they are Laravel helpers, and can be used in plain `.php` files. `asset()` is simply a helper to generate a URL to a specific asset; there should be an equivalent on in `pug`. `route()` is a little more complex, as it has to access the routing logic and find a named route based on the param.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `route()` as such:

```
each country in countries

  div(
    class="
        col-md-6
        col-lg-4
        my-padding-bottom-19
        my-filter-object
        my-country
      "

    data-controller="country"
    data-country-url-delete = route('countries.destroy', country)
  )

    .my-frame

      .my-padding-bottom-12.my-filter-target
        ##{ country.id }: #{country.label}
```